# Is there a way to stop all.vars() returning names from the right-hand side of $?

Tags: r, expression

The base-R function `all.vars()` returns all the names from an expression. For example:

```
> all.vars( ~ e == M * c^2  )
[1] "e" "M" "c"
```

There's one R operator for which this is inappropriate. In many expressions written by people who aren't using non-standard evaluation and functions from rlang and its like, names will be the names of variables. But if those expressions contain calls to `$` , the name on the right-hand side will not be a variable, but an index or column name. (I know the distinction between variables and column names can be blurred by clever use of environments and data masking, but that's not the point here.)

`all.vars()` doesn't have an option for ignoring the right-hand sides of `$` . Are there any similar functions that do, or must I program my own expression-walker? Basically, I want a function that if passed the expression

```
a $ b + c $ d
```

will return "a" and "c" .

**Reason for request**

Roland, it is good of you to suggest I explain why I want this. I use vectorisation much, since it's the only way to get sufficient speed in the calculations I do over very large datasets. Vast tracts of my code thus consist of this kind of thing:

```
cond <- ¢ A logical vector of 500,000 elements ¢
v1 ¢ (and v2 etc. ) ¢ <- ¢ Numerical or string vectors of the same length ¢
result_size <- length( cond )
result <- rep( NA, result_size )
result[ cond ] <- f( v1[ cond ], v3[ cond ]
                   , v4[ cond ], v7[ cond ]
                   , v9[ cond ], v10[ cond ] 
                   )
result[ ! cond ] <- g( v2[ ! cond ], v3[ ! cond ]
                     , v4[ ! cond ], v5[ ! cond ]
                     , v6[ ! cond ], v8[ ! cond ]
                     , v10[ ! cond ] 
                     )
```

That, I think, is what R experts call a split workflow. Split data by a condition, process each group separately, combine results.

This pattern is crying out to be abstracted into something that looks like a conditional. (See e.g. R. D. Tennant's book, *Semantics of Programming Languages* for examples of abstractions in this sense of the term and why they're good.) So instead of the accident-prone stuff above, replete with mistypeable and repetitious indices and partial-vector assignments, I want to be able to write:

```
cond <- ¢ A logical vector of 500,000 elements ¢
v1 ¢ (and v2 etc. ) ¢ <- ¢ Numerical or string vectors of the same length ¢
result <- splivif( cond
                 , f( v1, v3, v4, v7, v9, v10 ) 
                 , g( v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v8, v10 )
                 )
```

`splivif()` here should be interpreted as just another kind of conditional function, in the same way that `if()`, `if_else()`, `ifelse()` and `fifelse()`, and probably half-a-dozen others that I don't yet know are. It would hide some clever details in the same way that those functions do: namely evaluating its condition, splitting any variables mentioned in the "then" and "else" branches into subvectors according to that condition, calling each branch on those subvectors, and then combining the results.

Such a function is one that I have in fact implemented and use often. As said above, it first evaluates its condition. It then scans the "then" and "else" expressions for variables. Those that it deems to be vectors of the right length, it evaluates. It then selects only the `cond`'th elements of each value, and binds them, in a new environment, to the name of the original variable.

So, by the end of this stage, we have a new baby environment `E` in which the name "v1" is bound to `V1[ cond ]` , where `V1` is the value of the original `v1`. Also in `E` are similar bindings for names "v2" to "v10".

`splivif()` then evaluates its "then" and "else" expressions in `E`, and combines the results into a result vector.

My need for `all.vars()` was in scanning the "then" and "else" expressions for variables. I use nested named lists to store values that control my calculations. Therefore the expressions have a largish number of references to those lists' elements, for example `Taxogellation $ IgnoreRepeats` and `Taxogellation $ DoInnerSplines` . The nub of my question was that `all.vars()` would then incorrectly return "IgnoreRepeats" and "DoInnerSplines" as the names of variables when in fact they're indices.

**Code to demonstrate why I need to vectorise**

I added this section on September 8th 2020, in response to Roland's comment. It builds a table of sample data, representing the incomes, ages, and health of 50,000 families. Each family consists of either one or two adults. It then defines a function, `pension()` , which calculates the pension due to each family. This isn't the same as any existing government would give, but illustrates features of typical pension calculations. For example, the results typically depend on age and health, and may depend on income. These dependencies set a minumum complexity for any such calculation, and hence a minimum time.

The code then compares and times three ways of applying `pension()` to all 50,000 families. These are: grouping via the Tidyverse; grouping via data.table; and vectorisation. The latter uses the fact that operators and functions such as `+`, `|`, `>` and `pmax()` can be applied to vectors of more than one element, and then work elementwise on corresponding elements.

My timing results show that the Tidyverse, and even data.table, are woefully slow compared to vectorisation. For 50,000 families, vectorisation was 40 times quicker!

```
library( tidyverse )
library( data.table )
library( assertthat )
library( microbenchmark )
library( purrr )


#1) Create sample data
#=====================

# The code in this section makes a table
# of no_of_groups families. Each family has
# one or two adults. Adults are randomly assigned 
# an income, between 0 and 30,000 pounds;
# an age, between 18 and 99, and a health
# indicator. Each family also gets an integer
# ID. Each adult also gets a number indicating
# whether they are adult 1 or adult 2. 
#
# The sections following this will define
# a function for calculating families'
# pensions. My code will apply it in three
# ways, and time each one. These are: by
# grouping using the Tidyverse; by grouping
# using data.table; and by vectorisation.
# This shows that the Tidyverse and data.table
# are both woefully inefficient compared with
# vectorisation. For 5,000 families, the
# Tidyverse takes 2.5 seconds and data.table
# 2 seconds. Vectorisation takes a mere 50
# milliseconds, 40 times as fast.
#

no_of_groups <- 5000

group_sizes <- sample( c(1,2), no_of_groups, replace=TRUE )

ids <- 1:no_of_groups 

data <- tibble( fam_id=map2( ids, group_sizes, rep ) %>% unlist() )

data <-
  data %>%
    group_by( fam_id ) %>%
    mutate( ad_no = seq_along( fam_id )
          , two_people = length( ad_no ) == 2
          ) %>%
    ungroup() 

data $ income <- runif( nrow( data ), 0, 1 ) * 30000

data $ age <- sample( 18:99, nrow( data ), replace=TRUE )

data $ bad_health <- sample( c(T,F), nrow( data ), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1,0.9) )


#2) Function to calculate pension on single family
#=================================================

# two_people is true if the family has two
# people, otherwise false.
# ad1_inc and ad2_inc are the incomes, in
# pounds per year. ad2_inc is NA if there is
# only one person.
# Similarly, ad1_age and ad2_age are ages.
# And ad1_bad_health and ad2_bad_health are
# Booleans indicating whether the person
# has bad health.
# The result is the pension the Government
# gives the family, in pounds per week.
# This is NOT meant to be the same as in any
# existing country's social-security system,
# but exemplifies the kinds of calculation
# such a function needs to do. On our data,
# these will be called several hundred
# thousand times.
#
pension <- function( two_people
                   , ad1_inc, ad2_inc
                   , ad1_age, ad2_age 
                   , ad1_bad_health, ad2_bad_health
                   )
{
  max_age <- 
    ifelse( two_people
          , pmax( ad1_age, ad2_age )
          , ad1_age 
          )

  income <- 
    ifelse( two_people
          , ad1_inc + ad2_inc
          , ad1_inc
          )
 
  bad_health <-
   ifelse( two_people
         , ad1_bad_health | ad2_bad_health
         , ad1_bad_health
         )

  pension_level <-
    case_when( income > 50000 | max_age < 65 ~ "None"
             , max_age > 80 | bad_health ~ "High"
             , max_age >= 65 ~ "Normal"
             )

  pension <- 
    case_when( pension_level == "High" ~ 200.00
             , pension_level == "Normal" ~ 150.00
             , pension_level == "None" ~ 0
             )

  pension
}


#3) Check it works
#=================

pension( F, 40000, NA, 75, NA, F, NA )
# 150.

pension( T, 20000, 20000, 75, 75, F, F )
# 150.

pension( F, 60000, NA, 75, NA, F, NA )
# 0, because of high income.

pension( T, 30000, 30000, 75, 75, F, F )
# 0, because of high income.

pension( F, 60000, NA, 50, NA, F, NA )
# 0, because of low age.

pension( T, 20000, 20000, 75, 75, F, T )
# 200, because of bad health.


#4) Function to calculate all pensions using Tidyverse group-by
#==============================================================

pension_over_all_TV <- function( data )
{
  results <-
    data %>%
      group_by( fam_id ) %>%
      group_map( ~ {
                     assert_that( nrow( .x ) %in% c( 1, 2 ) )
                     two_people <- .x $ two_people[[ 1 ]]
                     pension( two_people
                            , .x $ income[[ 1 ]]
                            , ifelse( two_people, .x $ income[[ 2 ]], NA )
                            , .x $ age [[ 1 ]]
                            , ifelse( two_people, .x $ age[[ 2 ]], NA )
                            , .x $ bad_health[[ 1 ]] 
                            , ifelse( two_people, .x $ bad_health[[ 2 ]], NA )
                            )
                   }
               )
  #
  # A vector of pension values, one per family.

  results
}


#5) Try it and time it
#=====================

pensions_TV <- pension_over_all_TV( data )
#
# Pensions as calculated by Tidyverse grouping.

res <- microbenchmark( pension_over_all_TV( data ), times=3 )
print( res )
#
# Time it. Mean is 2.5 seconds:
#   Unit: seconds
#                        expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#   pension_over_all_TV(data) 2.533073 2.565714 2.584183 2.598356 2.609738 2.621121     3



#6) Function to calculate all pensions using data.table group-by
#===============================================================

pension_over_all_DT <- function( data )
{
  # The function that data.table must apply
  # to each group.
  #
  f <- function( group ) 
  {
    assert_that( nrow( group ) %in% c( 1, 2 ) )
    two_people <- group $ two_people[[ 1 ]]
    pension( two_people
           , group $ income[[ 1 ]]
           , ifelse( two_people, group $ income[[ 2 ]], NA )
           , group $ age [[ 1 ]]
           , ifelse( two_people, group $ age[[ 2 ]], NA )
           , group $ bad_health[[ 1 ]] 
           , ifelse( two_people, group $ bad_health[[ 2 ]], NA )
           )
  }

  data <- as.data.table( data )

  results <-
    data[
        , f( .SD )
        , by=c( "fam_id" ) 
        ]
  #
  # A table with a V1 column containing one
  # pension value per family.

  results
}


#7) Try it and time it
#=====================

pensions_DT <- pension_over_all_DT( data )
#
# Pensions as calculated by data.table grouping.

assert_that( are_equal( unlist( pensions_TV ), pensions_DT $ V1 ) )
#
# Making allowance for the slightly different 
# formats of the results returned by group_map()
# and data.table's grouped operations, check
# that the numbers are the same.

res <- microbenchmark( pension_over_all_DT( data ), times=3 )
print( res )
#
# Time it. Mean is 2 seconds:
#   Unit: seconds
#                        expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq     max neval
#   pension_over_all_DT(data) 1.824391 1.950273 2.155805 2.076154 2.321512 2.56687     3


#8) Function to calculate all pensions using vectorisation
#=========================================================

# This applies pension() to data by using vectorisation.
# It widens data into a table wherein each column is
# a vector corresponding to one of pension()'s arguments.
# It then calls exec() to apply pension() to these
# vectors. I had deliberately written pension() so that
# it would work on vector arguments with more than one
# element.
#
pension_over_all_Vect <- function( data )
{
  data_widened <-
    pivot_wider( data
               , names_from = "ad_no"
               , names_prefix = "ad"
               , values_from = all_of( c("income","age","bad_health") )
               ) %>%
    rename( ad1_inc="income_ad1", ad2_inc="income_ad2",
          , ad1_age="age_ad1", ad2_age="age_ad2"
          , ad1_bad_health="bad_health_ad1", ad2_bad_health="bad_health_ad2"
          ) %>%
    select( -fam_id )
  #
  # A table with one row for each family, and one
  # column for each of pension()'s arguments.

  results <- exec( pension, !!! as.list( data_widened ) )
  #
  # A vector of results: one pension value for
  # each family.

  results
}


#9) Try it and time it
#=====================

pensions_Vect <- pension_over_all_Vect( data )
#
# Returns a list of plausible-looking results.

assert_that( are_equal( unlist( pensions_TV ), pensions_Vect ) )
assert_that( are_equal( unlist( pensions_DT $ V1 ), pensions_Vect ) )
#
# Check that this is equal to the previously-
# calculated results.

res <- microbenchmark( pension_over_all_Vect( data ), times=3 )
print( res )
#
# Time it. The mean is 50 milliseconds.
#   Unit: milliseconds
#                          expr     min       lq    mean  median       uq     max neval
#   pension_over_all_Vect(data) 35.7834 45.23245 50.8431 54.6815 58.37295 62.0644     3
```

Comment: You seem to be reinventing the wheel. Why can't you simply use a group-by operation (either the data.table or the dplyr implementation)?

Comment: 1) A group-by operation needs more typing, due to the need to subset the vectors I pass as parameters (v1 to v10 in my examples). Note the repetition of "[ cond ]" and "[ ! cond ]" in the first code excerpt after "Reason for request". It would be easy to make a mistake in all those repeated subscripts. Or can you suggest a way round that?

Comment: 2) My code is a translation of code in a more conventional language, Python. I want the R to look as much like the Python as possible, so that the people who wrote the Python can check it. Since the Python uses conditionals, so should the R.

Comment: 3) Conceptually, I am writing a conditional, so my code should look like one. Even if it's implemented by group-by, that's an implementation detail, and doesn't need to be revealed to the person reading the code. I think this is the most important point of my three.

Comment: 4) @Roland, I may have misunderstood you. Did you mean use group-by *instead of* vectorisation? The reason is efficiency. I have half-a-million groups in my data. Processing it by vectorisation takes a few seconds. But the quickest group-by solution I could achieve takes 3 minutes. It's for an online model, and my users won't wait that long. I have always found that looping over data via group-by, whether in data.table or Tidyverse, is much slower than vectorisation.

Comment: Well, without a decent reproducible example I obviously don't fully understand what exactly you are trying to do. I stand by my point that you could probably achieve it (more) efficiently with data.table. If you are trying to mimic python, you will end up with bad R code.

Comment: I have added a decent reproducible example at the end of my question. I'm running on R 3.6.3: if you install the libraries mentioned at the top of the code, you should be able to run it on any R of roughly the same vintage. The example compares and times grouping with Tidyverse, grouping with data.table, and vectorisation. Vectorisation comes out as **40** times faster. Count it! Not 4 times; **40** times. Than data.table.

Comment: Your example is way too extensive. However, you are creating a false dichotomy: it's not "vectorization or data.table" it's "vectorization and data.table". Don't be surprised about bad performance if you use `ifelse`. Usually, that's a sign that you should use a join operation instead and these are blazing fast with data.table. I maintain that you are not optimally using the tools available and thereby making it more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: I disagree that the example is too extensive. It's the smallest I could make it and still illustrate why execution time is a worry. And indeed, why `ifelse` is a worry, something you've picked up on. Why should bad performance with `ifelse` not surprise me? I've tried data.table's `fifelse`, and that doesn't do significantly better.

Comment: As I said, you can probably use a join. An `ifelse` approach is conceptually slower and `ifelse` is also a slow function. `data.table` subset-assignment (by reference) is much faster. But you should probably refactor your code to use a join instead. (And if an example is too extensive doesn't depend on you. It depends on the time others are willing to spend on it.)

Comment: Could you send me a link to something that explains how to replace conditionals by joins? Or if you have a nice commented example from any code you've written, that would be great.

Comment: Simple example of an update join: `DT <- data.table(id = c(1, 2, 1)); lookup <- data.table(id = 1:2, letters = c("a", "b")); DT[lookup, letter := i.letters, on = "id"]`. More complex joins (rolling joins, non-equi joins) are possible.

Comment: I see how your lookup replaces a condition, thanks. For non-equi joins, I found Arun's example on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680641/conditional-inequality-join-in-data-table . But my conditions are pages long, with 3 or 4 levels of `if`. Because they describe Government regulations, which are horribly complex and obscure. To use non-equi joins, I'd have to move the conditions into the "on" subscript of a data.table. They'd be impossible to read, and multi-level stuff like "if A do ... if B do..." might not be possible. Have you successfully handled such complexity with joins?

Comment: You can join on more than one ID. That could be used to encode your nested conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You should explain why you need this and what should happen with other forms of non-standard evaluation. There might be a better solution to your actual issue.

I would quickly replace `$` with `[[`:

```
replace_dollar <- function(expr) {
  if (!is.language(expr) || length(expr) == 1L) return(expr)
  if (expr[[1]] == quote(`$`)) {
    expr[[1]] <- quote(`[[`)
    expr[[3]] <- as.character(expr[[3]])
  } else {
    for (i in seq_along(expr)[-1]) 
      expr[[i]] <- replace_dollar(expr[[i]])
  } 
  expr
}

expr <- quote(a $ b + c $ d)
replace_dollar(expr)
# a[["b"]] + c[["d"]]
all.vars(replace_dollar(expr))
#[1] "a" "c"
```

Note that according to the documentation:

> `x$name` is equivalent to `x[["name", exact = FALSE]]`.

I assume that you don't care about partial name matching here because you only want to pass to `all.vars`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `all.vars` options to output the whole structure including `$` operator, and remove the second argument of the `$` operator from the list :

```
    test <- ~a$b+c$d
    all <- all.vars(test,functions = T, unique = F)
    all
    #> [1] "~" "+" "$" "a" "b" "$" "c" "d"
    to_remove <- all[c(F,F,all == "$")]
    to_remove
    #> [1] "b" "d"
    vars <- all.vars(test)
    vars
    #> [1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
    vars[!vars %in% to_remove]
    #> [1] "a" "c"

<sup>Created on 2020-08-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>
```

Or as a function:

```
all.vars.new <- function(e) {
  all <- all.vars(e, functions = T,unique = F)
  cols <- all[c(F,F,all == "$")]
  vars <- all.vars(e)
  vars[!vars %in% cols]
}
```

Comment: @Phil van Kleur, did the answers solve your problem?